# How do i present a controller from a custom slide up menu

Tags: swift

Im trying to present a controller from a custom slide up menu in swift but at the moment when i select an option from the menu it doesn't present the controller.

at first i used apples alert controller which worked fine but i changed it to a custom created menu that slides in from the bottom of the screen that looks like this:

And i use the following class to build this:

```
class SettingsLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


let blackView = UIView()
let cellHeight = CGFloat(50)
let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 35, green: 35, blue: 35, alpha: 1)
    return cv
}()

let settings: [Setting] = {
   return [
        Setting(name: "Profile Settings", imageName: "gear"),
        Setting(name: "My Store", imageName: "bag"),
        Setting(name: "Search User", imageName: "magnifyingglass"),
        Setting(name: "Cancel", imageName: "xmark")
   ]
}()

override init() {
    super.init()
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
    collectionView.register(SettingsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier)
}

func showSettings() {
    
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss)))
        
        window.addSubview(blackView)
        window.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(settings.count) * cellHeight + 50
        let y = window.frame.height - height
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: window.frame.width, height: height)
        collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        
        blackView.frame = window.frame
        blackView.alpha = 0
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 1
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)

        } completion: { (nil) in
            
        }
    }
}

@objc func handleDismiss(setting: Setting) {
    
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            self.blackView.alpha = 0
            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
            }

        } completion: { (nil) in
            let mainTab = MainTabVC()
            mainTab.presentController(setting: setting)
    }
}


//MARK: - Collection View

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return settings.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! SettingsCell
    
    let setting = settings[indexPath.row]
    cell.setting = setting
    
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width
    print(width)
    return CGSize(width: width, height: cellHeight)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
    handleDismiss(setting: setting)
}
}
```

when i select one of the four items the menu is dismissed and a appropriate controller is to be presented but it doesn't work. this is how i have attempted to do it but i don't think it is correct:

So for example when a user selects the "Search User" it is supposed to execute the following:

this function is handled in another class called MainTabVC() which is where all the navbar items are configured and when they are pressed on it calls the above class to present the menu.

```
func presentController(setting: Setting) {
    if setting.name == "Search User" {
        let searchVC = SearchVC()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchVC)
        navigationController.title = "Search User"
        self.navigationController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print(setting.name)
    }
}
```

when a user selects an option that is not "Select User" the code is executed and it prints out the name of each setting but why does it not present the controller.

Any help would be helpful thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trigger the action with this way

```
let mainTab = MainTabVC()
mainTab.presentController(setting: setting)
```

you actually creating a new `MainTabVC()` which never included in any window and `UI` scheme.

You can start writing a protocol for communication.

```
protocol SettingsLauncherDelegate: class {
    func settingDidSelected(setting: Setting)
}
```

Then in `SettingsLauncher` class

```
class SettingsLauncher: NSObject {
    
    // add weak delegate variable
    weak var delegate: SettingsLauncherDelegate?
    
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let setting = self.settings[indexPath.item]
    delegate?.settingDidSelected(setting: setting)
}
```

Then go in your target `UIViewController` class

Conform your view controller to the protocol like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SettingsLauncherDelegate{
      let settingsLauncher = SettingsLauncher()
             
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        settingsLauncher.delegate = self
       }

      // this will be triggered when any action is selected
      func settingDidSelected(setting: Setting) {
        print("selected setting > ", setting)
      }
}
```

Then set the delegate variable of your custom `UIView` class to `self`.

This will solve your problem.